# Internal DNS Resolution in Java AppEngine System

Tags: google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

As many organizations do, we have a large footprint of internal infrastructure that is mapped behind internal DNS names (int.organization.com).  This DNS namespace is configured in a split DNS configuration where devices INSIDE our firewall can use our DNS servers to resolve the internal names, and external systems cannot resolve these.

As our teams expand to using AppEngine, we are having problems finding a pattern where we can continue to leverage internal/protected DNS entries (config.int.organization.com) rather than inadvertently exposing our infrastructure to public DNS.

Typically on Cloud Instances (VM's) we simply overwrite the /etc/resolv.conf to use our internal DNS servers (over VPN).  This works great.

For AppEngine (Managed VM's) and container engine, we do not seem to have a facility to override the resolv.conf (its mapped in read-only from the docker host).  We looked briefly at overriding DNS servers in Java and were unable to prove out that functionality.

Is using internal/private DNS servers just not a pattern that is compatible with AppEngine/ContainerEngine?  What patterns are people implementing to protect their infrastructure/naming?

Comment: Did you try overriding `/etc/resolv.conf` on Managed VM running in user-managed mode?

Answer (score 1):

**Java Specific DNS**

You may also be able to override the DNS servers specifically in your application using:

```
sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=<server1_ipaddr,server2_ipaddr ...>
```

Per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use directives in the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) of a [Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) (once "Managed VM") instance to edit system files, such as /etc/resolv.conf.